# $.address.value("/abc/") throwing error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a page with many links, and I am using `$.address.value("/abc/")` on click. When I click for the first time it works fine, but when I click the same link or another link for the second time it throws the error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

I am using the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $.address.internalChange(function (event) {
        if (event.value == "" || event.value == "/") {
            $("#maincontainer").html('');
        }
        else {
            var page = event.value.split('/');
            if (page[1] == "page1") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "page1.aspx",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#maincontainer").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (page[1] == "page2") {
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    });
})

function gotopage(pageid){
    if (pageid == 1) {
        alert(pageid);
        $.address.value("/page1/");
    }

    if (pageid == 2) {
        alert(pageid);
        $.address.value("/page2/");
    }
}

$("ul#navigation  li ul li").click(function (e) {
    gotopage($(this).attr("rel"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What is `address` in your code?

Comment: on click it takes rel value and from gotopage function gives address

Comment: sorry there, I don't understand. where do I initialize address. I have listed all the code I have.  I am very new to jquery.address-1.5

Comment: Just to confirm, is this the address plugin from http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ ?

Comment: yes.. I am using asual.com/jquery/address plugin

Answer (score 0):

Found easy solution as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $.address.strict(false);

        $.address.change(function (event) {
            if (event.value != "") {
                $("#content").load(event.value + '.aspx');
            }

            else { alert('load home page'); }
        });
    });
```

//---------------------------

```
<a href="Default2.aspx" rel="address:/default2">Default2</a> 
<a href="Default3.aspx" rel="address:/default3">Default3</a>
```